# ListView in a fragment Clickable and on item clicked listener

Tags: android, listview, onclick, android-fragments, onclicklistener

I have a listview in a fragment here is my current code for it:

```
public static class AllSectionFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public AllSectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tasks_all,
                container, false);
        // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Set up all components here:: ie text views , buttons lists etc.//
        // that correspond to the layout fragment xml file                //
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.fragment_tasks_all_textView);
        dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(
                ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));

        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        ListView allList = (ListView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.fragment_tasks_all_list);
        MyCustomAdapter mAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(getActivity(),
                arrayList); // Class to populate a ListView with an
                            // ArrayList
        allList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        // Populate array list
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            arrayList.add(" All Task " + i);
        }
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        return rootView;
    }

    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        System.out.println("pos: "+ position);
    }
}
```

and my layout.xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".TasksActivity$DummySectionFragment" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fragment_tasks_all_textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/fragment_tasks_all_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="0.41"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll" >

</ListView>
```

First of all. how can i make it so that i can click on an item in the list,

and second of all how do i add the onclick listener for it.

Comment: Ok i have got the on click listener working.. I just added: `allList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> p, View view,
      int position, long id) {
     System.out.println("pos: " + position);
    }
   }); `   but now when i click on the list view on the device it doesn't high light it or show it as being clicked. but my log cat shows that i clicked it.

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you just use ListFragment:

```
  public static class ArrayListFragment extends ListFragment {

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Shakespeare.TITLES));
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Log.i("FragmentList", "Item clicked: " + id);
    }
}
```

Comment: But then i can only put an array list in my fragment?  I can i still add buttons and text etc ?

Comment: why wont you separate this fragment for 2 or 3 fragment with their responsibilities. meaning create a separate ListFragment and a normal Fragment for your buttons and text. that way you can reuse them in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Use the alternative constructor for ArrayAdapter that allows you to specify a layout file to host your listview:

```
public ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and was resolved by **creating a interface with onClick method** and implementing it in fragment.
Try do this:

Create a interface:

**MyOnViewClickListener.java**

```
public interface MyOnViewClickListener {
    public void myOnViewClickListener(View v);
}
```

In your custom adapter class, **create a constructor** passing MyOnViewClickListener as argument:

```
private Context context;
private MyOnViewClickListener itemListener;
private List<String> items;

public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, List<String> items, MyOnViewClickListener itemListener) {

        this.itemListener = itemListener;
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
}
```

Inside **getView()** method, put:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_row_layout, parent, false);

TextView textView1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.quizchallenge);
    textView1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            itemListener.myOnViewClickListener(v);
        }
});
```

Finally, in your fragment class, **implement the new interface**:

```
public class ListFriendFragment extends Fragment implements MyOnViewClickListener  {
.
.
.
@Override
public void myOnViewClickListener(View v){
    //call your method
    quickQuiz();
}
```

Set up the adapter:

```
adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(getContext(), myItemsList, MyFragment.this);
```